# Homomorphism, showing that two mappings are the same.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group and suppose that every element of $G$ is a
product of elements of some subset $X\subset G$ (i.e., $G$ is
generated by $X$, so for each $g\in G$,
$g=x_1^{\pm1}x_2^{\pm1}\cdots x_k^{\pm1}$, where $x_i\in X$ for
$1\le i\le k$, but they are not necessarily distinct). Suppose
$f,g\colon G\to H$ are two homomorphisms so that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all
$x\in X$. Show that $f=g$.

So really want I want to show here is that the homomorphism $f$ equals the homomorphism $g$ So I should start by taking some element in $f$ and showing that it is in $g$ also. I then need to show this for all elements? Am I on the right track here or should I be using the definition of cyclic a lot?

Answer (score 3):

Be careful, $f$ and $g$ aren't sets, so there's nothing "in $f$" or "in" the function $g$.

You need to show that $f$ and $g$ are equal, as *functions* (one of which has an unfortunate name, since we've already used $g$ to stand for an arbitrary element of group $G$); that they agree at every element of their domain.

Thus, you'll need to pick some arbitrary group element $h \in G$, and show that $f$ and $g$ agree at $h$, that is, $f(h) = g(h)$. If this is the case, then $f$ and $g$ are equal, as functions, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

> "(...) So I should start by taking some element in f and showing that it is in g also (...)"

It appears you are somewhat confused with the definitions. After all, there is no mention of cyclicity in the hypothesis, so you can not use it.

To show that $f = g$ is to show that $f(x) = g(x)$ for every $x \in G$.

Fix, then, $x \in G$. By hypothesis, we can write $x = x_1^{j_1}x_2^{j_2}...x_n^{j_n}$, where $x_k \in X$ and $j_k = +-1$ for every $1 \leq k \leq n$. This way, we have

$f(x) = f(x_1^{j_1}x_2^{j_2}...x_n^{j_n}) = f(x_1^{j_1})f(x_2^{j_2})...f(x_n^{j_n}) = g(x_1^{j_1})g(x_2^{j_2})...g(x_n^{j_n}) = g(x_1^{j_1}x_2^{j_2}...x_n^{j_n}) = g(x)$,

since $f$ and $g$ are homomorphisms, and $x_k^{j_k} \in X$ for every $1 \leq k \leq n$.